# Step-CA doesn't work with server alternative names (SAN)

Tags: ssl-certificate

The help text for Step-CA when creating a certificate with SANs reads:

```
  Request a new certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names. The
  Subject Common Name of the certificate will be 'foobar'. However, because
  additional SANs are configured using the --san flag and 'foobar' is not one
  of these, 'foobar' will not be in the SAN extensions of the certificate.
  The certificate will have 2 IP Address extensions (1.1.1.1, 10.2.3.4) and 1
  DNS Name extension (hello.example.com):

      $ step ca certificate --san 1.1.1.1 --san hello.example.com --san 10.2.3.4 foobar internal.crt internal.key
```

When I try an equivalent command as follows:

```
step ca certificate --san dtk --san dtk.intranet.local foobar /root/dtk.crt /root/dtk.key
```

I get the following output:

```
✔ Provisioner: acme-smallstep (ACME)
Using Standalone Mode HTTP challenge to validate dtk .. done!
Using Standalone Mode HTTP challenge to validate dtk.dynautics.local .. done!
Waiting for Order to be 'ready' for finalization .. done!
Finalizing Order .error finalizing order: error finalizing order: CSR names do not match identifiers exactly: CSR names = [dtk dtk.dynautics.local foobar], Order names = [dtk dtk.dynautics.local]
```

If I replace "foobar" with an empty string it prompts me for the subject. If I replace "foobar" with "dtk dtk.dynautics.local" as a single string, I get:

```
Finalizing Order .error finalizing order: error finalizing order: CSR names do not match identifiers exactly: CSR names = [dtk dtk dtk.dynautics.local dtk.dynautics.local], Order names = [dtk dtk.dynautics.local]
```

I am confused. Surely SANs are a common thing? Surely this functionality was tested before Step-CA was released?

Why does their own example not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given by the Step-CA help text is all wrong. To solve this issue, use the main name as the subject. E.g.:

```
step ca certificate --san dtk --san dtk.intranet.local dtk.intranet.local /root/dtk.crt /root/dtk.key
```